# Set a custom application theme with gtkmm

Tags: linux, themes, overriding, gtkmm

I am developing a small business application, and my development environment is a Linux system. Anyway, I'm using libraries like Boost/GtkMM/SQLite, so it would be easy to port it to Windows systems (which is the target platform) or Mac. I'd like to let my application appear with the same theme on every platform, so is there any way to hardcode the theme or at least load it from C++? I suppose this kind of problem involves stuff like gtk-engines, but really don't know how to solve this trouble. Thanks in advice for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Gtk 2.4, there are RC files.  You can create a `gtkrc` file for your applicaiton's theme and then call a function to parse it on init.  This is what GIMP does on windows.

The GTK+ (C) docs are [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Resource-Files.html), but the gtkmm docs seem lacking.  Try `/usr/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/rc.h`.  For example:

```
Gtk::RC::add_default_file("some_file");
```

at least compiles for me.

For GTK 3 apparently there are now [CSS files](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html), which are *like* the CSS we all know and love(?) but not identical.